# SQL - Get data from one column depending on another column's value

Tags: sql, wordpress

I have a WordPress database with a table named `usermeta` that looks like this:

```
umeta_id | user_id | meta_key | meta_value
1        |    1    |first_name| Matt    
2        |    1    |   dob    | 1970-01-15
3        |    1    |  dl_num  | 10569788658
4        |    2    |first_name| Jim
5        |    2    |   dob    | 1985-07-29
6        |    2    |  dl_num  | 16578984258
```

I need to get the meta_value for a specific user if the meta_key is 'dl_num' and need an SQL query to do this.

I was doing something like this:

```
SELECT meta_value FROM usermeta WHERE user_id = 1 AND meta_key LIKE 'dl_num'
```

I am using this with other code in Wordpress that prints out my data into a .csv report and it doesn't pull in the data.

Here is a piece of my code:

```
case 'dl_num':
                        if ( $report_user instanceof WP_User ) {
                            $user_id2 = $report_user->ID;
                        }
                        if ( property_exists( $report_item, 'post_id' ) ) {
                            $post_id2 = $report_item->post_id;
                        }

                        global $wpdb;

                        $myRows = $wpdb->get_row( "SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$user_id2." AND meta_key LIKE 'dl_num'");

                        $column_value = $myRows;
                    break;
```

Could someone take a look and my SQL query and see if I am missing anything?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the lack of spaces in the query:

```
$myRows = $wpdb->get_row("SELECT meta_value FROM ".$wpdb->prefix."usermeta WHERE user_id = ".$user_id2." AND meta_key LIKE 'dl_num'");
```

Notes:

- You should print out the query after you construct it.  Then the answer would be obvious.
- You should use parameters, then you wouldn't have this type of problem.

Comment: So I added spaces to the SQL query and it had no effect. I am not sure what you mean by using parameters. Does anything else look wrong with my query? If not, I am sure it has something to do with the code.